# How to set cookie samesite attribute in weblogic.xml?

Tags: java, cookies, weblogic, samesite

I want to set cookie `'samesite'` attribute in weblogic deployment descriptor but don't see any option for `'samesite'` attribute like we have for `'httpOnly'` and `'Secure'`.

```
<cookie-http-only>true</cookie-http-only>
<cookie-secure>true</cookie-secure>
```

Is there any tag to set the `'samesite'` attribute?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cookie-domain put the value  ";SameSite=none"
Doing it in cookie-comment won't work since JSESSIONID is a version 0 cookie (netscape). I've searched for a way to activate version 1 without success.

Hope this helps as a workaround while the request is fulfilled by oracle and a patch will be soon available.

Comment: It works fine for Chrome and firefox, but old edge and ie versions are not even sending session cookies to first-party req itself. Can you suggest any common fix.

Answer (score 0):

There is bug/request filed under the number "28055873 : CSRF TOKEN IMPLEMENTATION FOR WEBLOGIC PRODUCT". So there isn't an option to use the samesite attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It's working after appending `";SameSite=none"` in `cookie-domain`:

```
<cookie-http-only>true</cookie-http-only>
<cookie-secure>true</cookie-secure>
<cookie-domain>.test.com;SameSite=none</cookie-domain>
```

Comment: Hi, From which version of weblogic did this start working?